# Vertx Http Client not working after setShared to true

Tags: vert.x

I got the following when I set **.setShared(true)** in my WebClientOptions:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedHttpClient cannot be cast to class io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl (io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedHttpClient and io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Comment: Can you [file an issue](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) on GH please?

Answer (score 0):

Was resolve in https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/2165

Just need to update **vertx-web** version to **4.2.8** or higher